# Change text in the menu "meta" sites in another language

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button, languages, localization, portuguese-stackoverflow

Am community user **StackOverflow em Português**.

The *meta* word is used as an adjective and for this reason the communities http://pt.stackoverflow.com, http://ja.stackoverflow.com and http://ru.stackoverflow.com the term usually appears after the community name, except in communities where English the adjective usually comes before the name.

[image: stackexchange menu]

But many times a day I go to the meta, the http://meta.stackoverflow.com by the *meta* word being in front I do not get confused, but in other stackoverflows the *meta* word is after the name and sometimes accidentally I clicked on the wrong community, for example:

Sometimes I'll go to the **StackOverflow em Portugues Meta** and end up clicking "Meta StackOverflow" (original StackOverflow) by mistake (I think my brain tries to look for the *meta* word that is most visible).

That instead of using -- *this is no urgent problem, just a suggestion*:

> StackOverflow em Português Meta

Communities in other languages would use something like this:

> Meta StackOverflow em Português

### Note:

In Portuguese language we use the adjective before (and after) the subject of the sentence, for example:

Using before:

> Uma garota bonita

Using after:

> Uma bela garota

Both sentences mean: *A beautiful girl*

Another point is that in Portuguese using the "meta" word always comes before the subject, eg:

`metalinguagem`, `metáfora`, `metástase` and `metafísica`.

> **Note:** Related in [Por que "Stack Overflow em Português Meta" e não "Meta Stack Overflow em Português"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3936/3635)